# Why can't I show my data with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my code :

```
  var xml=new String("");     
 //function to send data every 5 seconds
        window.setInterval(function() { 
        //code to obtain xml file
            alert(xml);// when I try alert my variable xml contain data
            ajax_post(xml);
            }
        }, 5000); 


  //the function ajax_post


   function ajax_post(xml){
   // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
   var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    var url = "my_file.php";
    var vars = "xml="+xml;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
    }
}
hr.send(vars);
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
```

The problem is when I try to show my data in a div I get an empty output, as if he let the variable initialised empty, yet with alert I can show my data.
Why ?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use vanilla js for this. Use jQuery, and one of their ajax methods. http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/ http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have an extra } where it shouldn't be:

```
window.setInterval(function() { 
        //code to obtain xml file
            alert(xml);// when I try alert my variable xml contain data
            ajax_post(xml);
            }
        , 5000);
```